# Error trying to use Passport Local Strategy in nodejs to login from username, email and mobile

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, mern, passport-local

I am doing an Instagram clone to learn and practice MERN.

I am using passport and passport-local to authenticate and login. I am trying to set the login so the user can login with username, email or mobile.

**Login controller function (runs when /login)**

```
export const login = (req, res) => {
    console.log("LOGIN")
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const { _id, username, privilege } = req.user;
        const token = signToken(_id); // Create jwt token since we signed in
        res.cookie('access_token', token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: true });
        res.status(200).json({ isAuthenticated: true, user: { username, privilege } });
    }
```

**Local Strategy of passport.js trying to let username, email or mobile as options to login**

```
export const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    console.log("LOGIN")
    // Check if user exists
    const criteria = (username.indexOf('@') >= 0) ? {email}
                     : (username.match(/^[0-9-+]+$/) !== null) ? {mobile}
                     : {username};
    console.log(criteria);

    User.findOne(criteria, (err, user) => {
            console.log(user);
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false); // No user exists

            user.comparePassword(password, done); // Check if password is correct (from UserModel)
    });
}));
```

Do I need to change anything else for it to work?
Thank you!

**edit: Fixed it, check answers for the solution**

Answer (score 1):

although I can see your entire code  let me mention some remarks
for your `LocalStrategy` to work you should require it from passport
`const LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy` also you should add functions to `serialize` and `deserialize` user

Comment: Hi, I could solve it thanks. I was importing passport-local. Did not added functions to serialize/deserialize user

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

```
export const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'loginOption',
    passwordField: 'password',
}, (loginOption, password, done) => {
    // Check if user exists
    User.findOne({ $or: [{ username: loginOption }, { email: loginOption }, { mobile: loginOption }] }, (err, user) => {
            console.log(user);
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false); // No user exists

            user.comparePassword(password, done); // Check if password is correct (from UserModel)
    });
}));
```